# Calculating if date picker + time picker are in the past of Eastern Standard Time zone

Tags: javascript, date

I've got a standard input type=date field that outputs a value such as "2016-03-28" when its posted, and a time picker that outputs a value like "10:30pm" when posted. I need to check if the combination of the date and time are in the past relative to the EST (eastern standard time zone). What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Calculate the date and time for Eastern Standard Time (presumably the US one) and see if it's before or after the date. What have you tried? Getting the time for a specific offset is not difficult.

Comment: Yeah I was overthinking it. I didn't know how the offset thing worked. I posted how I did it below.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it:

```
        var entryDate = $("input[name='launchDate']").val();
        var entryTime = $("input[name='launchtime']").val();
        var morningEvening = entryTime.slice(-2);
        var fixedTime;
        if (morningEvening === "am") {
          fixedTime = entryTime.split('am').join(' AM');
        } else {
          fixedTime = entryTime.split('pm').join(' PM');
        }

        var newDate = new Date(entryDate + " " + fixedTime);
        var inputDate = newDate.toLocaleString();
        var offset = -5.0;

        var clientDate = new Date();
        var utc = clientDate.getTime() + (clientDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);

        var newYork = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset));
        var newYorkDate = newYork.toLocaleString();

        if (inputDate < newYorkDate) {
          console.log("It's in the past");
        } else {
          console.log("It's in the future");
        }
```

Comment: Parsing strings with the Date constructor is **strongly** recommended against and comparing strings generated by *toLocaleString* (which is entirely implementation dependent and produces different results in different browsers) does not seem like a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Given separate inputs for date like 2016-03-28 and time like 10:30pm you should parse both to produce a Date. To treat the date as EST (presumably US -05:00), create the date using UTC methods and add 5 hours.

A Date for "now" will have a UTC time value so you can use that as–is, then just directly compare the Date objects:

```js
/* @param {string} ds - date string in format yyyy-mm-dd
** @param {string} ts - time string in format hh:mmap
** @returns {Date} Date with time value for equivalent EST time
*/
function parseDateTimeAsEST(ds, ts) {
  var b = ds.split(/\D/);
  var c = ts.split(/\D/);
  c[0] = +c[0] + (/pm$/i.test(ts)? 12 : 0);
  return new Date(Date.UTC(b[0], b[1]-1, b[2], c[0]+5, c[1]));
}

// Is now before or after 2016-03-28T22:30:00-05:00?
document.write(new Date() < parseDateTimeAsEST('2016-03-28','10:30pm')? 'before' : 'after');

document.write('<br>');

// Is now before or after 2016-04-01T01:30:00-05:00?
document.write(new Date() < parseDateTimeAsEST('2016-04-01','01:30am')? 'before' : 'after');
```